# Dark theme on Vue 3 PDF Reader

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, vuejs3, darkmode

I've added [@tato30/vue-pdf](https://github.com/TaTo30/VuePDF) library to my Vue 3 project and works as intended. After adding dark mode to my project, I've decided to also try to add dark mode to any PDF presented in it; after a test with CSS' [invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert) function; the desired result was achieved. Nonetheless my theme variable is a Vuex variable and I've trying to link it to my PDF reader so it can change properly but it doesn't work; my code is the following:

```html
<VuePDF
  align="center"
  :pdf="pdf"
  :page="currentPage"
  :scale="scale"
  :style="filter: invert('dark' === this.$store.getters.theme ? 1 : 0)"
/>
```

What is my mistake? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VuePDF
  align="center"
  :pdf="pdf"
  :page="currentPage"
  :scale="scale"
  :style="{ filter: invert(this.$store.getters.theme === 'dark' ? 1 : 0) }"
/>
```

Here is an explanation of the changes made:

1.The :style binding was missing a curly brace {} around the object containing the style property.

2.The invert function was not being called correctly. It was missing the parentheses () around its argument.

3.The comparison operator 'dark' === this.$store.getters.theme was using the wrong operator. It should be === instead of 'dark' ===.